# Domain Model with Nhibernate design issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I´m trying to get started in the “DDD with C#” world.
I use NHibernate as my ORM tool, thus trying to develop a PI(Persistence Ignorance) model. 
However, in some of my entities (which are being represented as POCOS) I have  business rules in the setters of my properties.
For example, I have a “User” entity which have a flag that indicates if this user is blocked or not, when this flag is true a second field called “Block Date”
 must be automatically filled whith the current date.
Everything seems very clear and simple, but the problem arises in the moment that I´m recovering users that has already persisted in the database, even though 
the blocked users will have their “Blocked Dates” update to the current date, according whit this logic.
Initially I thought in a second flag “isLoaded” that would indicates that the object is being hydrated by NHibernate and then this logic wouldn´t be launched,
 however this didn´t seem like PI. Any suggestion on how to improve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define field access strategy in your mapping for the IsBlocked property. Basically, you would say to NHibernate to use underlying private field (_isBlocked) instead of property and hence, your setter logic in IsBlocked property won't be executed.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339264/property-access-strategies-in-nhibernate) has a good answer on access strategies.

Official NHibernate [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property).

If you are using Fluent NHibernate for mapping, this is how you could define it:

```
Map(x => x.IsBlocked).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Miroslavs solution for the NHibernate problem, I'd really recommend moving away from putting logic behind property setters, especially when other fields need to be changed.

```
public void Block()
{
   _isBlocked = true;
   _blockedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451689/domain-driven-design-domain-objects-attitude-about-setters) for why.